# date "validation" using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i hope what i will be posting now will make more sense. so this is the thing i ve been trying to code this in javascript and the same error always occurs, been trying for a while now to figure it out but i can't seem to find the problem.

```
function isLeap(type)
    {
        var yr;
        try{
        yr=document.getElementById('yearof' + type).value;
            try{
            yr = parseInt(yr);
                if ((yr%4) == 0){
                    if (yr%100 == 0){
                        if (yr%400 != 0){
                            alert("Not Leap");
                            return "false";
                        }
                        if (yr%400 == 0){
                            alert("Leap");
                            return "true";
                        }
                    }
                    if (yr%100 != 0){
                        alert("Leap");
                        return "true";
                    }
                }
                if ((yr%4) != 0){
                    alert("Not Leap");
                    return "false";
                } 
            }
            catch(e){
            }
        }
        catch(e){
            break;
        }
    }

function monthDays(type){
        var month;
        var days;
        try{
        month=document.getElementById('monthof' + type).value;
            try{
            month = parseInt(month);
                if(month%2 != 0 || month == 8){
                    days= 31;
                }
                else{
                    if(month != 2){
                        days = 30;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(isLeap() == true){
                            days = 29;
                        }
                        else{
                            days = 28;
                        }
                    }
                }

                var mod=document.getElementById('dayof' + type);
                for(var i=1; i<13; i++){
                    var option=document.createElement("option");
                    option.text=i.toString();
                    try{
                        // for IE earlier than version 8
                        mob.add(option,mob.options[null]);
                    }
                    catch (e){
                        mob.add(option,null);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(e){
            }
        }
        catch(e){ 
            break;
        }
}
```

and this is the html

```
<select id="monthofbirthchild" class="month" name="monthofbirthchild" onchange="monthDays("birthchild")">
                                    <option value="MM">MM</option>
                                    </select>
<select id="monthofbirth" class="month" name="monthofbirth" onchange="monthDays("birth")">
                                        <option value="MM">MM</option>
                                    </select>
```

i am passing either 'birth' or 'birthchild' so that the appropriate  either for child or normal can be edited.

Comment: Can you post whatever you have tried till now?

Comment: Preventing a web programmer from using jQuery is like preventing a car making company from using wheels. It's stupid and it's wrong.

Comment: @ShadowWizard if you really need to make car analogy, it's much closer to power steering than _wheels_. The web without jQuery isn't missing anything; it's just harder to steer. (See what I did there?)

Comment: @Mathletics yeah, I didn't really give it MUCH thought. :)

Comment: its an assingment, and I've been having trouble figuring it out, will post what I did in a second.

Comment: Next time, prepare the Question before posting it ;)

Comment: Detecting a leap year is something this simple: `function getLeapDay (year) { if (year % 100 === 0) { return (year % 400 === 0) ? 1 : 0; } return (year % 4 === 0) ? 1 : 0; };`. It can be done even shorter way by using `Date` object, which I showed in my answer, which you didn't bother even to comment : (.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really did not see your answer, I am still very new to site. I still can't see the answer maybe because it's on hold, not sure tho. my problem is with the monthDays() method, I do not know why it is not populating my <select>. Sorry if I was rude not to see your answer but I really did not see it, and I cant find it :( @Teemu

Comment: @user3023347 Hmm... I've undeleted the answer, it's at the bottom of this page. Please check also the fiddle linked in the comment below the answer. It works cross-browser, though IE<9 need their own event handling attachment. In your current code you need also to [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) the newly created option to DOM, and IE<8 work without the hack you have. Also don't use `try..catch()`, it's easier to debug, when you can see the errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Date` object to get the last date of a month (which is the length of a month as well):

```
daysInMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
// daysInMonth = new Date(2012, 2, 0).getDate(); // --> 29
```

Actually `2` is March in the example. However, there's not 0th day in any month, hence the last date of the previous month is returned.

---

**EDIT**

Now when seeing also some code of yours...

You've a quoting error in the online eventhandlers. You need to put them this way:

```
onchange="monthDays('birth');"
```

If I can guess the rest of the HTML correctly, that (awful) JS code can be replaced with the simple function below.

```
function monthDays (type) {
    var month = parseInt(document.getElementById('monthof' + type).value, 10),
        days = new Date(document.getElementById('yearof' + type).value, month + 1, 0).getDate(),
        mod = document.getElementById('dayof' + type),
        i;
    mod.length = days;
    for(i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        mod[i].value = i + 1;
        mod[i].text = i + 1;
    }
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRSA9/).

Comment: @user3023347 This is not what you're asking for? I've extracted some (simplified) functions from my own ["DateHandler"](http://jsfiddle.net/NhqcC/) for you, maybe it gives you some ideas...

Comment: thanks alot this is exactly how I need it to work, dude I love you. sorry can t upvote your answer but previous question sent my rep down ^^. thanks again